# How to assign a trait method to child class object?

Tags: php

my question is very easy.I have a trait and child class.

```
trait mixVar {

public function go(){
return [];
}

}


class example extends foo { 

use mixVar;


public $var=$this->go(); //does not work

}
```

how to make this in php?

Comment: Create a function in class `example` or add to `__constructor`. Because values of class properties __must be defined__ at compile time

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a method call to assign a default value to a property. You would have to do it in the constructor.

```
class example extends foo 
{ 
    use mixVar;

    public $var;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->var = $this->go();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks friends.I tried with __construct and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to define trait method like:

```
trait mixVar {

    public function go(){
        $this->var = [];    // your value here
    }

}
```